# How to pass String Array from html input to Angular http Post?

Tags: java, angularjs, servlets, post

I want to pass some text input as array string to angular controller. I'm able to send single input as POST param and get it in Serlvet by using `String key = request.getParameter("key");`

This is my form

```
    <form ng-controller="FormController" ng-submit="submitForm()" class="ng-valid ng-scope ng-dirty ng-valid-parse">    
    <p>Text1: <input type="text" name="ancestor" ng-model="blob.ancestor" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched ng-empty"></p>
<p>Text2: <input type="text" name="ancestor" ng-model="blob.ancestor" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-empty ng-touched"></p>
<p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Confirm"></p>
</form>
```

and this is my js script:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('FormController', FormController);
FormController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$httpParamSerializerJQLike'];

function FormController($scope, $http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
    $scope.blob = {};
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        alert(JSON.stringify($scope.blob));
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/javaAngularJS',
            data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike($scope.blob),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;'
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Again, i'm able to send single param but i want to send "ancestor" with multiple values and get it using `String ancestors[] = reuest.getParameterValues("ancestor");` in my Post method on servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume that from your backend you are getting value of ancestor as `[1,2,3,4`] as array . you can bind this value to input field with `ng-repeat` like this

In Controller:

```
$scope.blob = {}; 
$scope.blob.ancestor = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

In HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="submitForm()" class="ng-valid ng-scope ng-dirty ng-valid-parse">
    <p ng-repeat="ancestor in blob.ancestor">Text {{$index +1}}: <input type="text" name="ancestor" ng-model="ancestor" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched ng-empty"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Confirm"></p>
</form>
```

Now in submitForm() click we will perform this to send data to backend in array

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {
    console.log($scope.blob); // result:{"ancestor":[1,2,3,4]} 
    $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080',
        method: "POST",
        params: {
            ancestor: $scope.blob.ancestor
        }
    }).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);

    }).error(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

The data will go in paramter and the url will look like this:

```
http://localhost:8080?ancestor=1&ancestor=2&ancestor=3&ancestor=4
```

Comment: thx! It worked for me. Btw, i'm using '.then(function successCallback(response) {}' insted of '.success(){}' that is deprecated for Angular version > 1.4.x